# How to embed an SVG image in a django template

Tags: django, svg, django-templates

I am trying to display an SVG image on a webpage built with a django template.

If I simply put

```html
<figure>
  <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="test.svg" width="75%" height="75%"/>
</figure>
```

in an HTML file then the SVG file is rendered (by Chrome).

But if I try to do the same thing in a django template it does not work.
I have also tried using

```html
 <iframe src="bar_chart.svg" width="200" height="200" ></iframe>
```

and a few other variations.

What is the best way in django to display SVG images?

Comment: Have you tried `<img src=....>` tag?

Comment: Ya i did. It was not rendering. If i  write it in html file only and open then it renders. But if i use that format in django template say display.html in templates dir then it dosent display. If i say <svg> draw circle</svg> then it draws circle. Basically djang cant refernce to the svg file. Based on wht i looked later it seems i have to use flask with_render method to render. I just dropped this library(pygal for svg files) and have started using chartkick python django library which is super easy.

Answer (score 10):

I would highly recommend using the SVG inline. During my previous job I tried to use object embedded in our Django project and my coworker's popup blockers blocked them.

Rename  the SVG to have an HTML extension put the SVG in one of your template directories and then use the include tag.

{% include 'bar_chart.svg' %}

The best thing about inline is that you can target anything in the SVG with css, bad thing is IE8 and older doesn't support it, same goes for android 2.3 and lower.

For more SVG goodness checkout https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 3):

As covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60505911/5920499) to a similar question, you can use the SVG `<use>` HTML element and `static` django template tag to achieve this:

```html
{% load static %}
<svg>
  <use 
    href="{% static "bar_chart.svg" %}#id_of_svg_element_to_include"
  >
  </use>
</svg>
```

But note that:

- the `svg` element in the SVG file you are referencing must have an ID that you can reference (`#id_of_svg_element_to_include` above)
- you must make sure that the ID is on the `svg` element not e.g. a `g` element else `width` and `height` on the `use` will not apply, as per [the note for the width and height attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#attr-r) on MDN.

The obvious benefit of not inlining is that the SVG can be served from your fast static file server and can be cached.

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom template tag I made for use with [the material design icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons). I download some icons as SVGs and place them in a folder. Their way of using a font is convenient, but takes a lot of bandwidth.

Example usage (selecting filename/class names/size/fill):

```
{% icon 'face' 'std-icon menu-icon' 32 '#ff0000' %}
```

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

ICON_DIR = "/path/to/your/icons/"

@register.simple_tag
def icon(file_name, class_str=None, size=24, fill='#000000'):
    """Inlines a SVG icon from linkcube/src/core/assets/templates/core.assets/icon

    Example usage:
        {% icon 'face' 'std-icon menu-icon' 32 '#ff0000' %}
    Parameter: file_name
        Name of the icon file excluded the .svg extention.
    Parameter: class_str
        Adds these class names, use "foo bar" to add multiple class names.
    Parameter: size
        An integer value that is applied in pixels as the width and height to
        the root element.
        The material.io icons are by default 24px x 24px.
    Parameter: fill
        Sets the fill color of the root element.
    Returns:
        XML to be inlined, i.e.:
        <svg width="..." height="..." fill="...">...</svg>
    """
    path = f'{ICON_DIR}/{file_name}.svg'
    ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    root.set('class', class_str)
    root.set('width', f'{size}px')
    root.set('height', f'{size}px')
    root.set('fill', fill)
    svg = ET.tostring(root, encoding="unicode", method="html")
    return mark_safe(svg)
```