# How to correctly include SVG sprite sheets in Django templates

Tags: django, svg

I created an SVG sprite sheet and am now looking at various ways of using it in my Django templates.

The easiest way is:

1. Add the spritesheet in the `templates/` folder (e.g. `templates/svg_spritesheet.svg`)
2. Include it in the Django template like so: `{% include "svg_spritesheet.svg" %}`
3. Call upon a given svg in the HTML code via: `<svg><use xlink:href="#my_svg"></use></svg>`

This has worked for me. But this method has operational imperfections.

For example: I normally park my static assets at `{{ STATIC_URL }}`. That is better for organization purposes. Secondly, I employ webserver level caching for assets in `{{ STATIC_URL }}`. I do not employ such caching for my `/templates` folder however.

So naturally, it seems to me that it would be better if I parked my SVG spritesheets at `{{ STATIC_URL }}`. But once I do that, how do I include it in my Django template?

None of the following methods work:

1. `{% include 'static/svg_spritesheet.svg' %}`
2. `{% include '{{ STATIC_URL }}svg_spritesheet.svg' %}`
3. `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="{{ STATIC_URL }}svg_spritesheet.svg"></object>`
4. `<link type="image/svg+xml" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}svg_spritesheet.svg">`

Can an expert give an illustrative example of how to use SVG sprite sheets that are placed at `{{ STATIC_URL }}`? Thanks in advance (in case warranted, I'm using `Django 1.8.19` for the project in question).

---

Note: in case you miss it - this question deals with **SVG sprite sheets**, not individual SVGs. A single sprite sheet contains multiple SVG images - which can be selectively called as (and when) required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was right under my nose.

Simply insert the required location when rendering an SVG from the spritesheet:

```html
{% load static %}
<svg>
  <use 
    href="{% static "svg_spritesheet.svg" %}#my_image"
  >
  </use>
</svg>
```

This way, you can keep your SVG spritesheets in the `static` folder - so all/any caching infrastructure fully applies. Happy coding!

Comment: After trying lots of non-working solutions this is the only one that made it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but in Django, the correct way to [load static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) is by using the staic tag.

Below I show a basic example:

**template.html**

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "svg_spritesheet.svg" %}" alt="My svg">
```

In this way, Django is responsible for managing the url and serve the svg, by using the corresponding storage `StaticFilesStorage`, which is not called if you generate the url manually

Comment: Are you certain I can use the `<img>` tag to load an SVG spritesheet?

Comment: Yes, you can see many ways of use svg in this [link](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/). But if you prefer, you can load it as a background in a `Div` or other tag with this css: `background: url({% static "svg_spritesheet.svg" %});`.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm referring to SVG spritesheet. So that contains 20 individual SVGs, which I selectively render whenever needed. This link: https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/

Comment: Ok, It would be something like this? [`django-svg-icons`](https://github.com/mikedingjan/django-svg-icons), whitch lets you load svg by symbol id from SVG Sprite.

Comment: Well, ideally I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a whole plugin

Answer (score 0):

`{{ STATIC_URL }}` did not work for me, so I amended it to

```
<svg><use xlink:href="{% static 'svg_spritesheet.svg' %}#my_image"></use></svg>
```